# Join two csv files based on name field

Tags: join

I have two tables with id and name. I want to join them based on the name field and output id and id.
File1:

> id, name
>
> a0N3000000A0JNaEAN,Guarda Val
>
> a0Na000000G8CCfEAN,Bentleys House
>
> a0Na000000EQVg6EAH,Alpine Lodge Resort
>
> a0N30000007LwcaEAC,Kulm Hotel

File2:

> id, name
>
> a0BQ00000013OeSMAU,Guarda Val
>
> a0BQ00000013OeBMAU,Bentleys House
>
> a0BQ00000013OeVMAU,Alpine Lodge Resort
>
> a0BQ0000001xlQoMAI,Kulm Hotel

What I wish  to see is:

> id.1, id.2
>
> a0N3000000A0JNaEAN,a0BQ00000013OeSMAU
>
> a0Na000000G8CCfEAN,a0BQ00000013OeBMAU
>
> a0Na000000EQVg6EAH,a0BQ00000013OeVMAU
>
> a0N30000007LwcaEAC,a0BQ0000001xlQoMAI

I have tried to scribble something, but the closest I've got was this:

> join -t, -a1 -a2 -1 2 -2 2 -o '0,1.2'  <(sort sandees.1.csv) <(sort prodees.1.csv)

Which just prints out the names. For the record, I am using OS X 10.8. I have seen that join behaviour might vary between different OSes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to get your input files as files; after that is working, you can use the fancier syntax.

The next thing is to do the sorting the way that `join` requires, namely sort each file on the second field instead of the first field. You need to use:

```
sort -t, -k2 sandees1.csv >sandees1_sorted.csv
sort -t, -k2 prodees1.csv >prodees1_sorted.csv
```

Your output format, `-o` specifies the key plus the second field of the first file. You said you wanted the first field of each file.

```
join -t, -a1 -a2 -1 2 -2 2 -o '1.1,2.1' sandees1_sorted.csv prodees1_sorted.csv
```

will produce the desired result.

Comment: Brilliant! I did indeed sorted them already, but found the previously post syntax and thought it might sort on the fly. The other question then - how does it deal with duplicate names (if it does) and how do I do inner join - just list the values that matches?

Comment: System 7 was the last time I did extensive work with `join` -- at that time, it would produce a second result for a second instance of the key, as no constraints (other than sorting) can be imposed by the architecture of `join`. Test it for yourself. I'm not sure what you mean by "inner join" in this context, as "join" means "inner join".